# Surjectivity of ring homomophism induced by Frobenius endomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

Denote by $F_q$ the finite field with $q$ elements, and denote by $\bar{F_q}$ its algebraic closure. Let $V$ be an affine $\bar{F_q}$-variety and $F$ be the Frobenius endomorphism corresponding to an $F_q$-structure $V(F_q)$ on $V$.

Let $R$ be the ring of polynomial functions of $V$, and $R=R(F_q)⊗\bar{F_q}$. The Frobenius endomorphism on $V$ induces a ring homorphism $F^*$ from $R$ to $R$ given by $f\otimes\lambda\mapsto f^q\otimes\lambda$.

Now turn to the question. It seems that $F^*$ is not surjective. Right? However, there is a statement as following.

Let $V$ be an affine $\bar{F_q}$-variety with ring of polynomial functions $R$. A surjective morphism $R$ to $R$ is the Frobenius endomorphism attached to an $F_q$-structure on $V$ if and only if for any $x\in R$ there exists n such that $F^{*n}(x)=x^{q^n}$.

Hence, I wonder that how $F^*$ can be surjective in the statement.

Is $F^*$ really surjective always?

Comment: $F : V \to V$ is supposed to be surjective, right?

Comment: No, I did not suppose so. Actually this question focus on $F^*$ which is induced by $F$. If $F^*$ is surjective, then $F$ is a closed embedding.

Comment: I don't quite understand all the words you are using (e.g. does an $\mathbb{F}_q$-structure mean it comes from a variety of $\mathbb{F}_q$?). So, I can't tell if you're looking at the Frobenius on $V\otimes\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ just acting on the second coordinate, or the 'absolute Frobenius' acting on the coordinate ring of $V$. In the former, it's clearly an automorphism. In the latter, it's not surjective in general--i.e. if $V=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{F}_q}$. Could you help me make sure I am understanding your question?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Firstly, $F_q$-structure means the coordinate ring $R=R(F_q)\otimes\bar{F_q}$, so your understanding is correct and I focus on the Frobenius on $V(F_q)\otimes\bar{F_q}$. Secondly, the Frobenius morphism in my question is the action on the coordinate ring, which is so called geometric Frobenius. See $f\otimes\lambda\mapsto f^q\otimes\lambda$. I shall be grateful if you may briefly tell the reason why it is an automorphism. Maybe I am confused, and I think that $F^*$ is only injective.

Comment: @Hebe I said that if it's the absolute Frobenius (i.e. the Frobenius on the coordinate ring) then it's NOT an automorphism. For example, the map $\mathbb{F}_q[T]\to\mathbb{F}_q[T]$ sending $f\mapsto f^p$ is not surjective. This is clear, and is related (equivalent) to the fact that $\mathbb{F}_q(T)$ is not perfect. Look at this page which lists all the various types of Frobenii, maybe it will be helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism ALSO, be sure to ping people in the future with (e.g. @Hebe) so they know you've responded.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, you are right. I think that I am misled by another guy who told me that the ring homorphism induced by geometric Frobenius is always surjective, which made me feel strange. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hebe No problem. :) You should answer your own question below, so people in the future can benefit from your insight.

Answer (score 1):

$F^*$ is not surjective in general. A counter-example is as following.

Let $V=\mathbb{A}^1$, and then $R=\bar{F_q}[T]=F_q[T]\bigotimes\bar{F_q}$. For each element $f(T)\otimes\lambda\in R$, we have $F^*(f(T)\otimes\lambda)=f(T)^q\otimes\lambda=f(T^q)\otimes\lambda$. It is obvious that $T\otimes1$ has no preimage.